# Find whether Esc key is pressed in resizing operation (MouseLeftButtonDown+MouseMove)

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, mouseevent, wpf-controls

In my WPF application, I have to find whether "Esc" key is pressed or not in `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` event (i.e. resizing operation).

I have tried below code in `MouseMove` event:

```
isEscapePressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape);
```

but `isEscapePressed` is true, when "Esc" key is in still holding state only. otherwise it is false.

I have tried to use `OnKeyDown` and `OnPreviewKeyDown` events also. but these are not triggered when mouse left button is in pressed state.

in my app, I am using `ContentControl` inside the Border and using `MouseMove` and `MouseLeftButtonDown` events of Border for resizing.

```
<Border>
   <ContentControl></ContentControl>
</Border>
```

Please give any idea for this case.

Comment: Can't you keep some state? You set an instance boolean to true in the KeyDown event when Escape is pressed, set it to false in KeyUp if the escape key is released. Then in your mouse move event you check that instance boolean for being true or false?

Comment: KeyDown event is not invoked when i press "Esc" key when mouse left button is pressed state.

Comment: I suspect you are blocking UI in mouse move event handler, this is why KeyDown. Can you show more code? See [mcve].

Comment: I have checked. I don't have any UI blocking code. in my app, i'm using ContentControl inside the Border and using MouseMove and MouseLeftButtonDown Event of Border for resizing.
<Border>
   <ContentControl></ContentControl>
</Border>

Comment: This is not the normal behavior. You either tested it wrong or you implemented it wrong. Since you have not provided any information, this can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can used following:

```
  private bool _isEscapePressed = false;
  private void MouseMoveEventHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
  {

     if (!_isEscapePressed && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape))
     {
        _isEscapePressed = true;

        // Code for Esc pressed down

     }
     else if (_isEscapePressed && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape))
     {
        _isEscapePressed = false;

        // Code for Esc released

     }

     // Mouse move code

  }
```